# Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance responses http request on both port 5000 and port 80

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

I setup an Elastic Beanstalk with load balancer forwarding port 80 to port 5000 on EC2 instance. My EC2 instance listens on port 5000, not port 80. The EC2 instance has a private ip 172.31.14.151. On another EC2 which is in the same subnet as the EC2 running the Springboot web server, I got http responses for the two following http request:

> curl 172.31.14.151:5000
>
> curl 172.31.14.151:80

I do not understand why I got http response from 172.31.14.15:80. The EC2 I am running the curl command is on the same subnet as the EC2 running webserver. The http request should not go through any router and not through load balancer. But the webserver is running on port 5000, not port 80.

Is there a Nginx instance running on the EC2 instance with webserver?

If I configure the webserver to listen on port 80 and let the Elastic loadbalancer forward port 80 to port 80 on EC2 instance, I got Nginx 502 bad gateway response from doing the curl request

> curl 172.31.14.151:80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which [Elastic Beanstalk Solution Stack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html) you are using, but most of the AWS Solution Stacks come coupled with Proxy Servers by default. For example, if you're running [Java SE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.java) the proxy server is NGINX, but if you're running [Java with Tomcat](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.java) the proxy server is Apache.

By default these proxies accept HTTP Traffic on the default HTTP port (`80`), manage the connections, then proxy the requests from the backing application server (In your case, port `5000`). This helps manage the connection to the backing application, as well as serve static content, or if you configure them correctly, customized Error messages based on the HTTP Status code. I'd suggest that if you can, you send the load balancer traffic to port `80` because Apache or NGINX can usually handle connection load better than most custom applications.

Comment: When creating an environment in Elastic Beanstalk, there are many choices for preconfigured platforms. Among them are Java and Tomcat. I choose Java. On the EC2, I see nginx, x-ray folders under /var/log. So it is a Java SE.  Since the nginx is running on the same EC2 as the webserver, and I have only one SpringBoot webserver running on the EC2, how does the Nginx help handle connection load on the EC2?

Comment: Yeah, nginx can do load balancing between multiple instances, but even at it's basic level, it will do buffering of requests and responses. Imagine you have a client attempting to connect to your system that has a slow connection, and they are uploading a file. If you don't have a proxy server, it will connect directly to your app server, and start using up one of your connections. With the proxy server, it will accept the request first, then open the connection to the app server, and pass it the value. Since they're on the same machine, this is fast. It also buffers responses in the same way.

Comment: See a link to the documentation where the use of the port 5000 is explained: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you check [inbound rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) on the security group that you've use ?

Is there a Nginx instance running on the EC2 instance with webserver? - Yes is it. When you create new environment, you can choose pre-configured platform, and choose [NodeJS Platform](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.nodejs).

If your application is heterogeneous applications, is better to use container. You can deploy your containerized applications on [Elasticbeanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.mcdocker) or use [Elastic Container Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) instead.